# Scan and print directories, subdirectories & files

Tags: python, python-2.7, subdirectory

I'm trying to get a nested view of directories and subdirectories in HTML, converted with Python. For example:

```
- dir
- dir
- dir
  - subdir
    - subdir
    - subdir
      - subdir
  - subdir
- dir
  - subdir
    - subdir
  - subdir
```

My Python code:

```
dirs = []

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(disk):
    dirs.append(dirName)
```

The array `dirs` is successfully created and filled, but I want to convert this array into nested HTML `<ul>` tags.

```
count = 0

for i in dirs:
    if count > 0:
        if dirs[count -1] in i:
            html += '<ul><li>' + i + '</li></ul>'
            previous = i
        else:
            html += '<li>' + i + '</li>'
    else:
        html += '<li>' + i + '</li>'

    count = count + 1
```

But how can I get the dir / subdir view example into a nested HTML `<ul>` tag, with nested items?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easier to use `os.lisdir()` and `os.path.isdir()` and a recursive function  to create the html you want , instead of using `os.walk()` .

Example -

```
import os
import os.path
def createHTML(d):
    res = '<ul>'
    lds = os.listdir(d)
    for l in lds:
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d,l)):
                    res += '<li>' + l
                    res += createHTML(os.path.join(d,l))
                    res += '</li>'
    res += '</ul>'
    return res
```

When I run the above, in one of my directories, I get -

- shared

  - pkg

    - __pycache__
- __pycache__

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine has developed a script to print directories recursively.

You should take a look at this : [MaxHalford/Directory-Architecture](https://github.com/MaxHalford/Directory-Architecture).
You will be able to ignore files with certain extensions or display *n* levels of directories.

Output example :

`sh
./probe example/`

```
example
├───┐ static
│   ├───┐ js
│   │   ├─── Leaflet.vector-markers.min.js
│   │   └─── Leaflet.vector-markers.js
│   ├───┐ data
│   │   └─── Toulouse.csv
│   └───┐ css
│       ├─── Leaflet.vector-markers.css
│       └─── Leaflet.vector-markers.css.map
├───┐ lib
│   ├─── __init__.py
│   └─── JCDecaux.py
├───┐ templates
│   └─── index.html
├─── serve.py
└─── update.py
```